# MS Access - Joining 2 view into a result table with fifo logic

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have 1 view like this (PurchaseOrder view)

```
PONo        Date        ProductId    Price   Amount 
PO 00001    01/07/2014  AS15         4.750   10.000 
PO 00002    02/07/2014  AS15         4.000   100.000 
PO 00003    05/07/2014  AS24         4.500   30.000 
PO 00004    06/07/2014  AS19         4.250   80.000 
PO 00005    08/07/2014  AS19         4.500   25.000 
PO 00006    09/07/2014  AS15         4.750   15.000 
PO 00007    11/07/2014  AS19         4.250   75.000 
PO 00008    12/07/2014  AS24         4.000   95.000
```

and summary of sales view (SalesSummary View)

```
ProductId    AmountSale 
AS15         35.000 
AS19         88.000 
AS24         50.000
```

I need tabel/view that resulted like this

```
PONo        Date        ProductId    Price   Amount      AmountSale 
PO 00001    01/07/2014  AS15         4.750   10.000      10.000 
PO 00002    02/07/2014  AS15         4.000   100.000     25.000 
PO 00003    05/07/2014  AS24         4.500   30.000      30.000 
PO 00004    06/07/2014  AS19         4.250   80.000      80.000 
PO 00005    08/07/2014  AS19         4.500   25.000      8.000 
PO 00006    09/07/2014  AS15         4.750   15.000      - 
PO 00007    11/07/2014  AS19         4.250   75.000      - 
PO 00008    12/07/2014  AS24         4.000   95.000      20.000
```

The first 5 field is same as the PurchaseOrderView.
The tricky part is how to get the AmountSale.This field is filled with FIFO logic 
from SalesSummary

Comment: What database are you using?  Also, you should explain the logic for getting the final result.

Comment: Thx gordon, you save my day. Iam using ms access 2007 the logic is to substract amountsale for same product in purchaseorder order by date.The old PO will deduct first then process to next PO. if amountsale in result less than amountsale in salessummary. I can say it's like fifo logic for inventory

Comment: I am only do the select into statement to a new table and set amountsale = 0. I need logic to update the AmountSale in that table the way i want

Comment: My best advice is basically to give up and switch to SQL Server 2012/2014 express.  This type of query is much easier in a database that better supports SQL functionality.

Comment: Can you help me with SQL Server logic for the problem above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont find a SQL Server solution, you can do this in Access.  Add this function to a public Module:

**EDIT:** Changed code to take into consideration when AmountSales does not full cover the first PO of the given ProductID.

**EDIT 2:** Noticed an error in logic and fixed it.

```
Public Function ReturnAmountSale(strPoNo As String, strProductID As String, curAmount As Currency, curAmountSale As Currency) As Variant

    Dim curAmountSaleUpToCurrentPO As Currency
    Dim varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO As Variant

    'Get the total Amount for the current ProductID up to and including given PO.
    curAmountSaleUpToCurrentPO = DSum("Amount", "PurchaseOrder", "[PoNo] <= '" & strPoNo & "' AND [ProductID] = '" & strProductID & "'")

    'If there is enough in SalesAmount to cover the whole cost, return the whole Amount.
    If curAmountSale - curAmountSaleUpToCurrentPO >= 0 Then
        ReturnAmountSale = Format(curAmount, "0.00")
    Else
        'Get the the total Amount in ProductID prior to current PO.
        varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO = DSum("Amount", "PurchaseOrder", "[PoNo] < '" & strPoNo & "' AND [ProductID] = '" & strProductID & "'")

        'If current PO is first in ProductID, varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO will be null;
        'determine covered amount.
        If IsNull(varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO) = True Then
            If curAmount <= curAmountSale Then
                ReturnAmountSale = Format(curAmount, "0.00")
            Else
                ReturnAmountSale = Format(curAmountSale, "0.00")
            End If
        Else
            'If current PO is not first in ProductID, varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO
            'will have a value; determine the covered amount.
            varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO = curAmountSale - varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO

            If varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO <= 0 Then
                ReturnAmountSale = Null
            Else
                ReturnAmountSale = Format(varAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO, "0.00")
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

And then add this column to your query (you can't have a column with a duplicate name of one in an existing table/query in the query, so thus the underscore):

```
Amount_Sale: ReturnAmountSale([PurchaseOrder].[PoNo],[PurchaseOrder].[ProductID],[PurchaseOrder].[Amount],[SalesSummary].[AmountSale])
```

NB: This assumes the PO's are issued successively in date order per ProductID.

Comment: @DanielFersbeanto: My results with the dataset your provided are exactly as the results dataset you posted above.  Can you please edit the dataset and results to give an example of what's going wrong and I will try to address?

Comment: I already try it and it work ok. Sorry, my bad. But I still can't figured out how to transfer paramet from my recordset to the function. So i must input the parameter manually. but the result is OK

Comment: Nah, that's ok.  As far as parameters, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807426/copy-selected-value-and-textbox-value-and-append-to-table-ms-access-vba/24825437#24825437.  Just the general idea of how to interact with Parameters in QueryDef.

Comment: Do You have an example how to manipulate a recordset, Use it as parameter for the above function ??? Because i am using recordset. Thanks before

Comment: No worries.  Check this, example with parameters near the bottom: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Thankssss, it'done and OK. SQL2 = "select * from TblStockDetail Order by ProductId,Date"
        Me.RecordSource = SQL2
        Set RS = Me.RecordsetClone
        RS.MoveFirst

        Do While Not RS.EOF
        RS.Edit
        RS!AmountSale = ReturnAmountSale (RS!PONo, RS!  ProductId, RS!Amount, RS!AmountSale)
        RS.Update
        RS.MoveNext

Comment: I got error message Run time error 94, Invalid use of null and pointing to curAmountSalePriorToCurrentPO = curAmountSale - DSum("Amount", "PurchaseOrder", "[PONo] < '" & strPoNo & "' AND ProductId = '" & strProductID & "'")

Comment: It only happen if amountsale for the first record less than stock

Comment: @DanielFersbeanto: If you can just edit the test dataset and results to add in the record values which would cause problems, I will take a look.  I have an idea of what you mean but rather deal with what it is than what I think it is.  Don't think it's a hard fix.

Comment: @DanielFersbeanto: Actually, I see the problem.  Give me a bit.

Comment: I already try the new code and the error invalid null is not show up anymore . so it's OK. But, I have one more setback.  I think the logic is prioritize the PONo sorting more than any sort that i made for recordset. It not work well if i have backdated PONo (example PO00002 with date before PO00001). But it actually work very well if the PONo is in line with PODate

Comment: I think it can be done with change the parameter strpono with PoDate and ignore the PONo. But I think it will come with a problem, if there ara more than one PO for the first date with same productid

Comment: @DanielFersbeanto: Yes, Daniel, I agree with your last statement.  You can possibly do a check on both PODate and PoNo.  However, this will be a problem inherent with the data and not the code. You'll need to see what's best for you.

Comment: After do the thinktank, I think it can be done with a help of row number. So, sorting the data by Product and Date, then give a row number to all data. Then run the Dsum by row number and product id. Can you help me on this? Please..

Comment: It Solved, I make 1 table with auto number for PurchaseOrder and inserted to that table order by Product,Date,PONo. Then I use the autonumber as substitute for strPONo and it run perfectly

Comment: @DanielFersbeanto: Yes, Daniel, you are correct about the auto numbering!  Glad it worked out for you! =)